# Generating XMl from DataContext

Tags: c#, xml, linq

What is the modification needed in the following code to get XML from DataContext?

```
DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
var query=new XElement("Numbers",
                                 from p in dc.Pack
                                 select new 
                                           {
                                                   XElement("Number",p.PK),
                                                    XElement("Value",p.Value)
                                            }
                         );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting an anonymous type that has two XElement properties. If by "get XML from the DataContext" you mean that you want to construct a valid XElement hierarchy, you need to be selecting two separate XElements.

Try using the Union operator to select multiple objects, rather than selecting an anonymous type with two properties.

```
DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
var query=new XElement("Numbers",
                        (from p in dc.Pack
                         select new XElement("Number",p.PK)
                        ).Union(from p in dc.Pack
                                select new XElement("Value", p2Value))
                       );
```

Answer (score 0):

would this be a hierarchical load?  If so, do:

from p in dc.Pack
select new XElement("root", 
   new XElement("Number", p.PK),
   new XElement("Value", p2Value));